# How can I save the partner belonging to a user via the spring-security-ui?

Tags: spring, postgresql, grails

I'm working on a web interface in Grails and use spring-security-core and a PostgreSQL database.
I would like to link a partner (company) database to the user database.
The linking has already succeded I can see this via the command line.

Now I would like to login on the spring-security-ui and when I create a new user that you can then select which partner (company) the user belongs to and also save it.
I manged to make a dropdown with the partners in the partner (company) database.
Creating a user with a partner (company id) has already succeeded via the command line.

The complete code can be found on github with the following link https://github.com/rm93/BIGC.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer. I need to save the partner id and not the whole name as I did.